How do I change env variables after getting build?
I am dealing with a project written with SvelteKit. In some cases, I need to change the .env files when there is a change in the servers I get the build from and I need to get the build every time I change it. What I'm wondering is that I can make changes to appsettings.json even after I get the build in my ASP.NET project and I just need to restart it through IIS. How can I do the same thing in SvelteKit and how can I access it from inside?

Env variables do not necessarily need to be static, have you looked at the dynamic modules?
